# How do I open an application in a Windows guest VM with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to open an application in Windows guest (I'm using a windows 7 base box from modernIE) after installing its pre-requisites. But I can't seem to open an application through vagrant shell scripts.

The script which executes the app gets stuck in the host terminal, and the guest shows no changes. I'm a beginner to Vagrant, and may be I'm missing something basic. My vagrant file looks like this :

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "modernIE/w7-ie10"
    config.vm.box_check_update = false
    config.vm.synced_folder "syncedFolder/", "C:/Files/"
    config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = true
        vb.cpus = 2
        vb.memory = "2048"
        vb.name = "Test"
    end
    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "test.bat"
end
```

test.bat:

```
cd %PROGRAMFILES%/Eclipse/
eclipse.exe -product com.ibm.rational.rft.product.id
```

I have changed eclipse to something like calc and it still doesn't open an app in Windows guest VM.